# MySql - how to store orders that can ship to multiple people

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a checkout where someone can buy gifts for one or more persons on the same order. This means one order, can actually be shipped 1,2,3 or more individuals under the same order umbrella. I'm trying to find a way to represent this in the database. Below is what I'm thinking. The `orders` table stores the basic order info ,the `order_groups` is so I can relate the items and shipping to a single person for the order, the `order_items` are the products, the `order_shipping` is self explanatory.

```
orders
id, amount, customer_id

order_groups
id, order_id

order_items
id, item_id, unit_price, quantity, total_price, order_group_id

order_shipping
id, name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, order_group_id
```

I believe this is okay, but I have a feeling the order_groups may not be the way to go. I'm asking if this is an okay way to do it, or if there is a better solution to the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your life will be much more simple if each and every order is a part of a group, even if it's the only order in the group.

Thus said, you should keep a reference to a group in the order itself, not in a link table:

```
groups
id, [group-related info]

orders
id, group_id, amount, customer_id
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you mean. Does the [group-related info] mean store info in the groups table or, keep the items and shipping tables as is with the group_id?

Comment: @Naterade: you should store group-related data (like the payment info, paying customer info etc.) in groups, and order-related data (shipping addresses, receiving customer info etc.) in orders. Order items should be linked to orders, not groups.

Comment: Ah, I see! I think that is a much better solution and more logical from a data representation standpoint. Thanks!~

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a possible one to many relationship.

```
order_addresses (table)
order_id, address_id

order_shipping (table)
address_id, name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, order_group_id
```

You'll also need to keep track of which items are being shipped to which address and you'll need to use a similar strategy.